# How can I find out if a string contanis a char?

Tags: java

Is there any way to check to see if a string contains a char?  Like create an if statement that will check a string to see if has a certain char in it but the char is a variable that is user inputted?

Comment: Please read that javadoc of the `String` class.

Comment: The javadoc of the String class is available [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), check out the [contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) method

Comment: What 2 people thought "_This question shows research effort_"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like thie

```
if(stringVar.contains(String.valueOf(charValue)))
{
 //do somethinng
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)

> Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified character...

So, given:

```
String string = "Hello"

string.indexOf('H') == 0
string.indexOf('e') == 1
string.indexOf('l') == 2
string.indexOf('l') == 3
string.indexOf('o') == 4
string.indexOf('n') == -1
```

If your string doesn't contain the `char` you're checking for, it will return a value of `-1`. So to see if your string contains a `char`, you are looking for:

```
boolean contains = string.indexOf(char_value) > -1;
```

Or

```
boolean contains = string.indexOf(char_value) != -1;
```

Comment: Would this be more efficient that string.contains(CharSequence c) since we are just dealing with a single character?

Comment: @DannyBit - you could answer that for yourself by reading the source code and/or do your own benchmarking.

Answer (score 1):

String has a contains method that takes a CharSequence (string, stringbuilder), so you take your character convert it to a String with String.valueOf(character c) and give it as a parameter to contains.

```
char c = 'a';
String myString = "stringa";
if (myString.contains(String.valueOf(c)){
     // code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "contains" method of the string class. Example:

```
if(yourString.contains("a")){
    //It contains an "a"
}
```

Comment: Actually, it contains an `a`, not `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes

```
String myString = "Some String";
char myChar = 'S';
char myChar2 = 's';
```

Method 1:

```
if(myString.contains(String.valueOf(myChar))) {} //True
if(myString.contains(String.valueOf(myChar2))) {} //False
```

Method 2:

```
if(myString.indexOf(myChar) > -1) {} //True
if(myString.indexOf(myChar2) > -1) {} //False
```